# How to control the number of images built in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

In a dotnet docker multiple stages build process, let say I have a dockerfile, which is intended to:
a. clone a repo
b. build it at a machine
c. publish it to another machine to run
My Dockerfile is like below:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest AS build-env
# git clone
# install dotnet sdk
# dotnet build
# dotnet publish to /publish directory
FROM ubuntu:21.04 AS run-env
# COPY the executable at the /publish directory at {build-env} to this image
```

Then, when I run

```
docker build -f Dockerfile -t myapp:run .
```

it shows

```
Step 1/2 : FROM ubuntu:latest AS build-env
---> jsd767ksv783
Step 2/2 : FROM ubuntu:21.04 AS run-env
---> djf675kdf034
Successfully built djf675kdf034
Successfully tagged myapp:run
```

Although it shows at the end that image djf675kdf034 (run-env) is built successfully and tagged with myapp:run. But it actually creates another image jsd767ksv783 (build-env).
It looks like to me that each FROM command will create a new image.
The problem is that I only need the final run-env image, the build-env is just temp for me and I do not need it after the build is successful.

Is there any way for me to specify this in Dockerfile?

Comment: That output is from the "classic" Docker build backend, and if you [use the newer BuildKit backend](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/) it will create fewer intermediate images.  You can't tell `docker build` not to create the first-stage image but you can `docker system prune` it.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks for the answer and the recommendation about BuildKit. Would you mind posting your comment as an answer to my question so that I can mark it as solution?